# Channel deadlocks when I add select default statement in goroutine

Tags: go, deadlock, channel

I'm learning channel and below is a test I tried, but deadlock happens

```golang
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        select {
        case ch <- 1:
            fmt.Println("send suc")
        default: // if comment this line, it will run smoothly
            fmt.Println("default")
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(2) // do some time consuming thing...
    fmt.Printf("receive val: %d", <-ch)
}
```

I expected there is no deadlock, but result is:

```golang
default
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

But if I remove `default` or `time.Sleep(2)`, code will run smoothly, result:

```golang
send suc
receive val: 1
```

Can someone explain why deadlock happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a `select` with `default`, that means if none of the communication ops are ready, `select` **will not wait, will not block**, but execute `default` immediately. The channel is unbuffered, so the send on it is not ready (because there are no receivers ready – `main` is sleeping).

So once the sleep is over in `main`, it tries to receive from the channel, but by then there is nobody trying to send on it. Deadlock.